# modernizr utilze the shapes value (how to)

Tags: modernizr

accessing modernizr.github.io/Modernizr/test/ suit I see shapes: false.

How can I use this  with modernizr?

Many thanks P

if (Modernizr.shapes) {

```
/*do something*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual feature detects in the github repo usually contain notes about the tests, and what they accomplish. This data will be visible once the 3.0 version of the site comes out.

This particular test is testing for CSS shapes, and the [notes](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/85ee9d75ed83164b62fee7d1c8f78e8438a071f9/feature-detects/css/shapes.js#L6-L15) list the [Adobe examples](http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/layout/shapes), and a [codepen demo](http://codepen.io/collection/qFesk)